# interdependant dropdown list Jquery Knockout asp.net

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

i've been scratching my head for a while now with this issue.

Assume i have a concatenated field which goes like A-B-C. i have a set of object that goes like {[A1-B1-C2],[A1-B1-C1],[A2-B2-C3],...} and so on.

I am using the select2 plugin to build a filter to filter this set of object. Problem is, filter on A,B,C have to be interdependant. so if i choose A1 in the A values dropdown i will have B1 in the B dropdown as selectable value and C2 and C1 in the C values dropdown. if i set my filter B with B1 in the first place i should have A1 in A dropdown list and C1 and C2 in C dropdown. A,B,C dropdown contains a "all" default value at the beginning. but when i start playing around with values, dropdown lists need to be repopulate.

Problem comes when i am removing value, i can't seem to find the best way to handle it. let's take the following scenario with the same data set above. so first i have the "all" value in my three dependant dropdown lists. then i choose A1 in the first one. so in B i have B1 as a choice and in C in have C1 and C2 as choices. now a select B1 in the B dropdown, i loose my all option in the A dropdown list and still have C1 and C2 in the C dropdown (at this point C has no value selected and don't have the "all" option anymore). Now i decide to empty my A dropdown. so as B dropdown is the only selected option i need to make all B values available again meaning B1, B2 and "all" option again.

I hope i'm clear enough, and hope i'll get some help on it too. I already have a solution which is to send ajax query everytime a change happens but i find it too heavy. for now on A has 2 possibles value and B around 20 possible values, C can have an infinite set of value.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to use a subscribable, or computed, though I can't be sure without more details. The computed is probably a little more practical, here's the best example I could come up with. Subscribables work pretty similarly but are easier to use when using AJAX calls.

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.SelectedCategory = ko.observable();
  self.SecondCategory = ko.observable();
  self.Choices = ko.observableArray([
    "Hats", "Jackets", "Shoes"
  ])

  self.DependantChoices = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.SelectedCategory() == "Hats") {
      return ["Top Hats", "Baseball Caps"];
    }
    if (self.SelectedCategory() == "Jackets") {
      return ["Winter Jackets", "Summer Jackets"];
    }
    if (self.SelectedCategory() == "Shoes") {
      return ["Dance Shoes", "Athletic Shoes"];
    }
  })

  self.SecondDependantChoices = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.SecondCategory() == "Top Hats") {
      return ["White", "Black"];
    }
    if (self.SecondCategory() == "Baseball Caps") {
      return ["Blue Team", "Red Team"];
    }
    if (self.SecondCategory() == "Winter Jackets") {
      return ["Puffy Jackets", "Long Jackets"];
    }
    if (self.SecondCategory() == "Summer Jackets") {
      return ["Leather Jackets", "No Jacket, it's summer"];
    }
    if (self.SecondCategory() == "Dance Shoes") {
      return ["Fast Dance Shoes", "Slow Dance Shoes"];
    }
    if (self.SecondCategory() == "Athletic Shoes") {
      return ["Running Shoes", "Programmers Shoes"];
    }
  })

}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: Choices, value: SelectedCategory">

</select>

<select data-bind="options: DependantChoices,value:SecondCategory">

</select>

<select data-bind="options: SecondDependantChoices">

</select>
```